# Library to evaluate excel/other language expression evaluation in java without using excel

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, expression-evaluation

I have been searching the internet for a library which can evaluate excel formula-like expressions in java The formula is not embedded in the excel.

Let's say, the values are not in excel either Let's say 3 variables `a`, `b`, `c` I want an evaluator in java which given a string like `CONCAT(a,b,c)` written in excel expression or in some other language, can give me the output.

I have found some expression evaluator libraries for java online, but there I need to define my own expression language, is there something which directly uses excel language or some other language?

I have looked at apache `POI` and `jxls` also looked at `jsp.el` as far as I have understood `poi` and `jxls` do the evaluations from formulas already embedded in the excel file or we need to create a spreadsheet to actually run the formula which `imo` will be heavier than running the formula in java. For `jsp.el` I'll have to define my own expression language, which is not robust enough.

Comment: Did you try and benchmark it? Creating a single sheet workbook in-memory using Apache POI, with a few formulas in, and evaluating ought to be pretty quick

Comment: As already answered by Axel, **But this workbook must not necessarily stored somewhere. It can be only in random access memory too** is what I wanted to know. I thought it was creating an excel in the computer. Now, I'll benchmark and check if I am not in a time crunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that `apache poi`'s `WorkbookEvaluator` needs a workbook. And since you are talking about evaluating "excel formula-like expressions", this is necessary because all variables in such formulas must either be cell references or names in that workbook. Your given example `CONCATENATE(a,b,c)` can only work as an `Excel` formula when `a`, `b`, and `c` are `Excel` names . Else it would lead to `#Name?` error in `Excel`. And btw.: The `Excel` function is `CONCATENATE` and not `CONCAT`.

But this workbook must not necessarily stored somewhere. It can be only in random access memory too.

And the formulas itself need not to be in the sheet somewhere. The formula can also be given as a string since there is [WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(java.lang.String formula, CellReference ref)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/WorkbookEvaluator.html#evaluate-java.lang.String-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference-).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Name;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

public class EvaluateExcelFunctions {

 static Object evaluateExcelFormula(String formula, Workbook workbookWithVariables) {
  if (workbookWithVariables.getNumberOfSheets() < 1) workbookWithVariables.createSheet();
  CellReference reference = new CellReference(workbookWithVariables.getSheetName(0), 0 , 0, false, false);
  CreationHelper helper = workbookWithVariables.getCreationHelper();
  FormulaEvaluator formulaevaluator = helper.createFormulaEvaluator();
  WorkbookEvaluator workbookevaluator = ((BaseFormulaEvaluator)formulaevaluator)._getWorkbookEvaluator();
  ValueEval valueeval = null;
  try {
   valueeval = workbookevaluator.evaluate(formula, reference);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   return ex.toString();
  }
  if (valueeval instanceof StringValueEval) {
   String result = ((StringValueEval)valueeval).getStringValue();
   return result;
  } else if (valueeval instanceof NumericValueEval) {
   double result = ((NumericValueEval)valueeval).getNumberValue();
   return result;
  } else if (valueeval instanceof ErrorEval) {
   String result = ((ErrorEval)valueeval).getErrorString();
   return result;
  }
  return null;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = 
   //new XSSFWorkbook();
   new HSSFWorkbook();

  Name name;
  String formula;
  Object result;

  // example 1 concatenating strings - your example
  name = workbook.createName();
  name.setNameName("_a");
  name.setRefersToFormula("\"Text A \"");
  name = workbook.createName();
  name.setNameName("_b");
  name.setRefersToFormula("\"Text B \"");
  name = workbook.createName();
  name.setNameName("_c");
  name.setRefersToFormula("\"Text C \"");

  formula = "CONCATENATE(_a, _b, _c)";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  // example 2 Pythagorean theorem
  name = workbook.getName("_a"); 
  name.setRefersToFormula("12.34");
  name = workbook.getName("_b");
  name.setRefersToFormula("56.78");

  formula = "SQRT(_a^2 + _b^2)";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  // example 3 complex math formula
  name = workbook.getName("_a"); 
  name.setRefersToFormula("12.34");
  name = workbook.getName("_b");
  name.setRefersToFormula("56.78");
  name = workbook.getName("_c");
  name.setRefersToFormula("90.12");

  formula = "((_a+_b+_c)*_c/_b-_a)/2";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  // example 4 faulty formulas
  name = workbook.getName("_a"); 
  name.setRefersToFormula("56.78");
  name = workbook.getName("_b");
  name.setRefersToFormula("190.12");
  name = workbook.getName("_c");
  name.setRefersToFormula("\"text\"");

  formula = "_a + _c";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  formula = "((_a + _b";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  formula = "_a \\ 2";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  formula = "_a^_b";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  formula = "_a/(_b-_b)";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  formula = "CONCAT(_a, _b)";
  result = evaluateExcelFormula(formula, workbook);
  System.out.println(result);

  workbook.close();
 }  
}
```

This code is tested using `apache poi 4.1.0`.

Note, `Excel` names cannot  be all possible variable names. For example a `Excel` name cannot be `c` or `C` because this would be in conflict with possible `R1C1` cell references. That's why I have named my names `_a`, `_b` and `_c`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry if the question was a bit unclear. I was not certain how to frame it properly. But this is what I was looking for. I'll now benchmark this against a self-made formula evaluator and see if the performance difference was high. Also **But this workbook must not necessarily stored somewhere. It can be only in random access memory too.** is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

To use IF function, I had to create a Cell instance to prevent a NullPointerException:

```
Cell cell = workbookWithVariables.getSheet(workbookWithVariables.getSheetName(0)).createRow(0).createCell(0);
CellReference reference = new CellReference(cell);
```